# "if" statement won't work on Debian Linux

Tags: linux, sh

I have a bash script which contains the following "if" statement. The problem is I can't get it to run on Debian (it runs fine on Fedora and CentOS).

```
if [ $1 == "--daily" ]  # <--- line 116
then
countDaily
elif [ $1 == "--monthly" ] # <--- line 119
then
countMonthly
fi
```

after running it:

```
sh /home/kris/countsc.sh --daily
```

I'm getting an error:

```
/home/kris/countsc.sh: 116: [: --daily: unexpected operator
/home/kris/countsc.sh: 119: [: --daily: unexpected operator
```

Comment: You tagged the question `bash`, but you are not using the bash shell.

Comment: Furthermore, you should include a shebang line to select a shell interpreter for your script. Otherwise the user has no clue which dialect the script is written in and might interpret a bash script using a POSIX shell. With a shebang line the script can be made executable, then it picks the correct shell automatically.

Comment: @Marco I have a `#!/bin/bash` line at the begining of this script. I've just not included it here.

Comment: But you are you not using it. Instead you are interpreting the script with the POSIX shell. The shebang line is not used if you provide the script as an argument to a shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using `sh`, and not bash, you should use a single equal `=` to do the string comparison, instead of the double equal `==`. Also it is a good practice to double quote the variable in test statement (this error is not caused by incorrect quoting though).

The comparison should be:

```
if [ "$1" = "--daily" ]
```

and

```
elif [ "$1" = "--monthly" ]
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but I was also able to run it like that: `if [ "$1"=="--daily" ]` and `elif [ "$1"=="--monthly" ]` (without spaces). Strange.

Comment: @soulreaver If you don't have spaces, then the whole block `"$1"=="--daily"` is considered one string. Since the string is non-empty, the command will always evaluate to true

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there is no double-equal operator in `test`, which is used in this case. If you want to test for string equality, just use a single equals sign, like this :

```
if [ $1 = "--daily" ]
elif [ $1 = "--monthly" ]
```

You should also remember to wrap `$1` into quotes in case it contains spaces.

You might also want to consider using the "new test" instruction in Bash, e.g. `[[` and corresponding `]]`, which has many advantages over `[`, which is a leftover from the days of sh. Check out [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) document in order to find out about the advantages.

Comment: It depends on what version of `test` you're using. If you use a version of `sh` that doesn't have `[` as a built-in command, and you have GNU coreutils installed, then the `[` command will recognize `==`  as a synonym for `=`. (You definitely shouldn't depend on that.)