# GIT_COMMIT not defined in index-filter

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

It seems as if $GIT_COMMIT is undefined in my index-filter. I would expect it to be. Am I wrong?

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'if [ $GIT_COMMIT == c69b26453cab89f9833b32a786f551ea18e5ff47 ]; then echo hello world; fi' c69b26453cab89f9833b32a786f551ea18e5ff47^..HEAD

Rewrite 3de628334c72b7b573a9cb2836110a5a8a8b2d70 (1/1) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    /usr/lib/git-core/git-filter-branch: 1: [: 3de628334c72b7b573a9cb2836110a5a8a8b2d70: unexpected operator
```

Comment: I'm not sure which OS you are on, and `[ x == y ]` works on all my variants, but the `test` documentation describes only the `=` operator, not the `==` one. Perhaps your `test` only accepts one equals sign?

Comment: @torek, yes, that was it.

Comment: A decent answer about this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828196/if-statement-wont-work-on-debian-linux/18828322#comment27779492_18828319)